# C++ typecast error

Tags: c++, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [void pointers: difference between C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736833/void-pointers-difference-between-c-and-c)

Hi I have the following function:

```
void task2(int a)
{
    printf("  Task 2 running..\n");
    sleep(2);
    printf("  Task 2 exiting..\n");
}

thpool_add_work(threadpool, (void*)task2, (void*)a);

int thpool_add_work(thpool_t* tp_p, void *(*function_p)(void*), void* arg_p)
{
    // some code here
}
```

The above code works well with C, but does not compile in C++. I'm getting the following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’
error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘int thpool_add_work(thpool_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’
```

I'm not able to figure out the reason for this error. Any idea why this error crops up when I change the file extension to CPP and compile?

Comment: You need to post more code – such as the declarations of the functions and objects.

Comment: Isn't this because `void*` is implicitly convertible in `C`, but not in `C++`?

Comment: In C++ it's not legal to convert a data pointer (i.e. `void*`) to a function pointer (i.e. `void* (*)(void*)`). However many compilers will let you get away with this. I would either remove or adjust the cast of `task2` you make when you  call `thread_add_work`. I'd also remove the `(void*)` cast of `a` which seems to serve no purpose. Too many casts is always a bad sign, it just hides errors

Comment: what is task2? is it a function?

Comment: Just updated the content of task2 in the question

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the signature of `task2` to match the type of the `thpool_add_work` argument:

```
void* task2(void* a)
```

The call which creates the thread would become

```
thpool_add_work(threadpool, task2, &a);
```

assuming that `a` is `int`.

If you need to use the argument of `task2`, you could do following:

```
int ia = *(int*)a;
```

**Update to answer the OP comment**

`thpool_add_work` expects a function with `void*` argument for a reason. In such a way, you can pass any kind of parameter into the thread function, albeit in a type-unsafe way.

You pass the address of the parameter converted to `void*` as the 3rd argument of `thpool_add_work`. Afterwards, you cast a pointer to `void` back to the pointer to your expected parameter type and dereference it to get the value of the parameter. I gave the example for `int a` above, now how it would look for a float:

```
void* test3(void* a)
{
float fa = *(float*)a;
.....
return NULL;
}
```

Comment: task2 needs to convert it into an int, and task3 need to convert the void* into a float. I'm not sure how changing the parameter to void* a will help. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @webgenius: The answer is updated

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
thpool_add_work(threadpool, (void* (*)(void*))task2, (void*)a);
```

C converts `void*` to any type automatically, C++ does not.

You could improve the code with a typedef

```
typedef void* (*worker_func_t)(void*);

thpool_add_work(threadpool, (worker_func_t)task2, (void*)a);

int thpool_add_work(thpool_t* tp_p, worker_func_t function_p, void* arg_p)
{
    // some code here
}
```