# Is explicit type conversion necessary in A a = (A) b;

Tags: c

I am reading some open-source C code and encountering `A a = (A) b;` type conversion many times. For example,

```
static void hexdump(const void* pv, int len)
{
  const unsigned char* p = (const unsigned char*) pv;
  // some other code
}
```

`A a = (A) b;` code happens mainly when `b` is a pointer,  `void *` pointer most often. I have C++ background. I think in C++, the assignment operator takes`=` care of the type conversion automatically? Because it already know that `a` is of type `A`.

Is the explicit type conversion necessary in C?

Comment: Your "update" is in the wrong place.  When you're getting answers that don't address the question, add comments below the answers asking for clarification, and then *fix your question.*  Tacking on an update to your question does not provide notification to anyone; nobody will see your "update."

Comment: About your update: depends on the type of A and B. BTW pointer conversion and type conversion are different things (as a quick general rule: promotions to compatible types are implicit, everything else is not). What "promotion" and "compatible" mean (in various contexts) is a long and different story...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, conversion from `void*` to `char*` in C (it's a [common example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736833/void-pointers-difference-between-c-and-c) to explain where they're different!) is implicit so casting is unnecessary (then *wrong* because it may hide a problem if you wrongly change `char` to `int`).

Quoting "*The C Programming Language*, 2nd edition" by K&R (**§A.6.8**):

> Any pointer to an object may be converted to type void* without loss of information. If the result is converted back to the original pointer type, the original pointer is recovered. Unlike the pointer-to-pointer conversions discussed in Par.A.6.6, which generally require an explicit cast, pointers may be assigned to and from pointers of type void*, and may be compared with them.

Please note *"If the result is converted back to the original pointer type"* because is crucial: if instead of `char*` you had `int*` then it *may* be wrong because of memory alignment.

From C99 standard (**§6.3.2.3**) about when conversion is possible:

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

Now let's see when can be implicit (thanks to mafso for very quick search), from C11 (n1570) **§6.5.4p3**:

> Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast.

Then **§6.5.16.1**:

> One of the following shall hold: [...] the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right

Answer (score 4):

You've got it the other way around: the cast is absolutely necessary in C++, but it is not necessary in C.

This [will compile in C](http://ideone.com/kXnkIU), but [not in C++](http://ideone.com/QnXZPs):

```
static void hexdump(const void* pv, int len) {
  const unsigned char* p = pv;
  ...
}
```

Comment: In C++, if b is not a ``void *`` type, then we seldom do ``(A) b`` when we assign it to ``A a``.

Comment: @PengZhang Generally speaking, C++ wanted to make casting feel rather uncomfortable to programmers, while at the same time reducing the need for use of `void*`. Requiring an explicit cast of `void*` is part of the same philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary in C but it helps silent compiler warnings for implicit casts in some cases.

In C++ however you need explicit casts to cast a void pointer into a pointer of a different type.

Comment: I've never got any warnings when implicitly assigning a `void *` to a pointer of any other type, however.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Which warning you will get depends on the compiler you are using. Some compilers with strong focus on C++ create warnings for code that is valid in C but not valid in C++.

Answer (score 1):

In my practice, no casting at first, though there's compiler warnings, after testing pass, casting is added to eliminate warnings.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are making a cast.

You are just saying for the compile. Hey, I'm sure that this is a type (A).

C++ style casts are checked by the compiler. C style casts aren't and can fail at runtime

Answer (score 0):

It's called a **cast**. It means that it converts b in the (A) type.

```
char c = 'a'; // c is a char
int b = (int) c // you tell your compiler to interpret c as an int
```