# Conversion from HGDIOBJ to HBRUSH

Tags: c++, winapi, g++

(This question is asked in the context of Win32API using the g++ compiler).
I have a trouble with understanding why the following line of code won't work

```
wndclass.hbrBackground = GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
```

wndclass is an instance of the WNDCLASSEX structure, and the Windows API clearly specifies that
the type of its member hbrBackground is HBRUSH. Further, HBRUSH is just a typedef for a HANDLE, which in turn is a typedef for void*. Hence, HBRUSH should be of type void*.
Now, the GetStockObject function's return type is HGDIOBJ, which is also typedefed as a HANDLE, hence a void*.

Windows Data Types
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

GetStockObject
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144925(v=vs.85).aspx

WNDCLASSEX
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577(v=vs.85).aspx

Why then do I get the following error upon compilation:

```
invalid conversion from 'HGDIOBJ {aka void*}' to 'HBRUSH' [-fpermissive]
```

If I explicitly cast the returned value from GetStockObject it works

```
wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because implicit conversions from `void*` are disallowed in C++ (unlike C).

Function

```
HGDIOBJ GetStockObject(int fnObject);
```

returns `HGDIOBJ` which is defined as `void*`:

```
typedef void NEAR* HGDIOBJ;
```

You are assingning it to HBRUSH which is a `typedef` to pointer to `struct`

```
struct HBRUSH__;
typedef struct HBRUSH__ *HBRUSH;
```

(see `windef.h`)

While such assignment works fine in C, in C++ you should explicitly cast :

```
wndclass.hbrBackground = static_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
```

See: [void pointers: difference between C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736833/void-pointers-difference-between-c-and-c)

#### Edit:

As *jensa* noted in comments, the article [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx) is wildly outdated. This is putting it mildly. I don't remember when it's happened exactly, but `STRICT Type Checking` was enabled by default since decades. This article was probably written in the last century (a 20th one).

Here is the quote of the comment by `yic81` from `10/7/2012`

> This article needs reviewing.
>   When was it last reviewed? 15 years ago?
>   The statement typedef HANDLE HINSTANCE; is totally incorrect, as many
>   other typedef HANDLEs. Vast majority of them are now DECLARE_HANDLE()
>   structs. Please review and fix this  article. See this KB83456
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/83456 (last updated November 1999) for
>   more details

You can also learn more about `STRICT` and it's advantages here: [STRICT Type Checking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383732.aspx)

And here is how it looks like in `windef.h`:

```
DECLARE_HANDLE(HBRUSH);
```

And somewhere below `DECLARE_HANDLE` defined as:

```
#ifdef STRICT
typedef void *HANDLE;
#if 0 && (_MSC_VER > 1000)
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__; typedef struct name##__ *name
#else
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__{int unused;}; typedef struct name##__ *name
#endif
#else
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) typedef HANDLE name
#endif
```

By default, we are using `DECLARE_HANDLE` from line 6. With `NO_STRICT` -- lines 9-10.

Comment: I see, thanks for you answer. However, in the link I provided (Windows Data Types) it clearly says: typedef HANDLE HBRUSH; Is this documentation out-of-date?

Comment: @jensa It depends whether `STRICT` is defined or not. If yes, the Win32 opaque object types have distinct types. If no, they're all `void*`. In the current headers `STRICT` is defined as `1` by default unless `NO_STRICT` is defined.

Comment: @jensa I've improved my answer by adding some info about `STRICT`.

Comment: @Drop Thanks for the update, especielly the information about the terribly outdated Windows Data Types documentation page. I'll look in the header files from now on!

Answer (score 2):

In C++ terms, you can say that `GetStockObject` returns a `GDIBase*`, and it requires a cast to appropriate derived class conversion (for example, assume `HBrushGDI`). Therefore, you must typecast.

```
class GDIBase;
class HBrushGDI : GDIBase;
GDIBase* GetStockObject(int);


HBrushGDI* pBrush;
pBrush = static_cast<HBrushGDI*>GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
```

It as same as typecasting a function-pointer returned from `GetProcAddress`. Therefore typecasting to appropriate type is safe (assume you *know* the correct type).