# C code in C++ incompatible parameter error

Tags: c++

In C this part of code works fine but in C++ i get an error:

> argument of type "void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "FILE
>   *"

How can i fix it? This is the relevant part of code:

```
static size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
    {

        curl_off_t nread;

        size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream); /*i get an error on this line on stream */

        nread = (curl_off_t)retcode;

        fprintf(stderr, "*** We read %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T
            " bytes from file\n", nread);
        return retcode;

    }
```

The solution was simple actually in the end.So if it helps anyone i simply changed void* with FILE *ptr and FILE *stream and it worked

Comment: When speaking French to an English guy you get the same problem. C and C++ are different languages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [void pointers: difference between C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736833/void-pointers-difference-between-c-and-c)

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to compile C code with a C++ compiler. That's what C compilers are for.

Answer (score 3):

```
   size_t retcode = fread((FILE*)ptr, size, nmemb, stream); /*i get an error on this line on stream */
```

That's the quick and dirty answer.  My question would be, if ptr is always a pointer to a `FILE`, then why declare the parameter as void*?

[void pointers: difference between C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736833/void-pointers-difference-between-c-and-c) has all the explanation you might ever desire.  I've flagged this question as a duplicate, but wanted to get you over this hump in the short term.

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit more rather than just posting a code snippet? This helps ensure high quality answers across SO. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

C allows automatic conversions between `void*` and pointers of other types:

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

Hence, it is OK to use `ptr` in a call to a function that expects a `FILE*`.

C++ allows automatic conversion from pointers of other types to `void*` but it does not allow automatic conversion from `void*` to pointers of other types.

Hence you get the compiler error.

Comment: @Raven, Glad to hear that you have a resolution.