# Cast pointer to reference pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

In the code below I am casting pointer type to reference pointer type in order to change the pointer to point somewhere else:

```
inline void SWAP_POINTERS(void*& p1,void*& p2)
{
    void* temp = p1;
    p1 = p2;
    p2 = temp;
}
```

When I call the function I ge the following error:

```
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int32_t *' (aka 'int *') to 'void *&' for 1st argument
```

Do I need to cast?
Why do I need to cast since it is void*?

Limitation: no templates.

calling the code like this:

```
unsigned int* a;
double* b;

SWAP_POINTERS(a,b);
```

Comment: This function screams "template" to me.

Comment: forgot to mention, i can not use templates

Comment: I think the problem is probably the call to `SWAP_POINTERS` not the  function itself. How does the call look like at the point you're using it?

Comment: Then you should consider writing in C++ which has templates.

Comment: You're not asking c++ to implicitly convert to void * -- that would be fine.  it isn't a void *.  It is a void *&.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [void pointers: difference between C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736833/void-pointers-difference-between-c-and-c)

Comment: Downvoted the question for incompleteness.  It should be possible to compile the code and reproduce the error.

Comment: why not use pointer to pointer (**) to simplify thing ?

Comment: Why don't you use `std::swap`?

Comment: @user31264: in otker words, this question lacks [mcve]

Comment: why don't you just use templates?  You're probably using a bunch of other things that use templates already.

Comment: @Kapil presumably because they parameters shouldn't be nullable.

Comment: no templates. long story !  ,i added full function call, std::swap is a template, in terms of pointers cast, i am failing to cast from unsigned int* to void* &

Comment: No templates? Use a Macro then. If you want to program in C, use the tools C gives you :(

Comment: the code above is a macro , i am asking for help on how to write it!

Comment: As already pointed out the problem is not in function but the way you are calling it.Please share how you are making call to this function

Comment: i did... i edited the question..

Comment: "no templates" You have to write a separate function for each pointer type you want to swap. It is undefined behaviour to use a cast here. Perhaps you can automate this with a macro or something.

Comment: this is one of the way in which you can make call  int x=10;
  int y=12;
  int *p1=&x;
  int *p2 = &y;
  void *p3 = (void*)p1;
  void *p4 = (void*) p2;
  SWAP_POINTERS(p3,p4);

Comment: @shd - No, it's not a macro. It's an inline function. Use `#define` to create a macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you think you want, but it's totally NOT recommended. Templates  (or `std::swap`) really are the right answer here.

First, define an inline function to take `void **`

```
inline void SWAP_POINTERS2(void** p1,void** p2)
{
    void* temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}
```

Then, define a macro to perform unpleasant casts.

```
#define SWAP_POINTERS(a,b) SWAP_POINTERS2((void **) &a, (void **) &b)
```

Or, if you prefer using `static_cast`:

```
  #define SWAP_POINTERS(a,b) SWAP_POINTERS2(static_cast<void**>(static_cast<void *> (&a)), static_cast<void**>(static_cast<void *>(&b)))
```

Now this "works" to the extent that it compiles and does what you want. I have no idea how you'd then use the swapped pointers, of course...

```
unsigned int* a;
double* b;

SWAP_POINTERS(a,b);
```

Comment: Note this invokes undefined behaviour, so your compiler is allowed to turn you into a newt upon seeing this.

Comment: @n.m. Is it UB if both `a` and `b` are `int*`?

Comment: yes it is. `int*` and `void*` are not even guaranteed to have same size.

Comment: @n.m.But assigning `int**` to `void*` and back IS guaranteed to work, surely? I've added a version using `static_cast` if that makes you any happier. :)

Comment: No, your program cannot be fixed with casts. Assigning int** to void* and back is not the same as taking an address of `int*`, pretending there's a `void*` at that address, **and putting another `void*` there**. Just imagine a machine where `sizeof(int*)==8` and `sizeof(void*)==10`. You have two 8-byte values to swap, and your function swaps two 10-byte values. No matter what casts you use, you cannot change these basic facts.

Comment: @n.m. But in many cases compiler must do the 8:10:8 thing for you. `int *a;void *v = a; int *b = (int *) v;` If you think that's invalid, how could `malloc`work?

Comment: The compiler can deal with it when doing assignment, not when reinterpreting bits. `int i = 7.0;` is OK. `*(double*)&i = 7.0;` is not. It's the same thing here.

Answer (score 4):

**1. You're probably breaking strict aliasing once you dereference one of the pointers after swapping.**

```
unsigned int* a;
double* b;
SWAP_POINTERS(a,b);
```

Don't swap pointers which do not point to the same type however. (Note that `char` aliases other types but that is an exception.)

**2. You cannot convert `int*` to `void*&` implicitly.**

`int*` is implicitly convertible to `void*` but the conversion creates an rvalue which cannot be bound to an lvalue reference.

In order to use `SWAP_POINTERS` with the signature shown in the question, one would have to create lvalues of type `void*` first and pass those to `SWAP_POINTERS`.

Example:

```
int a{0}, b{1};
int * pa = &a;
void * vpa = pa;
int * pb = &b;
void * vpb = pb;
SWAP_POINTERS(vpa, vpb); // swaps vpa and vpb - OF COURSE :)
```

*Please note that this doesn't solve the (probably inteded) swapping of (unrelated) pointers with minimal code. Its just an explanation of why the original code with `void*&` in place did not work when passing `int*` and how a call to the original function would have to look in order to be able to operate (on its function arguments...).*

**3. Swap pointers via `std::swap`**

```
int a{0}, b{1};
int * pa = &a;
int * pb = &b;
std::swap(pa, pb);
```

Comment: i see the "trick" you did, but i was hoping for shorter answer to solve the casting issue.  but the rvalue answer "solves" the casting by stating no other way to do this. thanks !

Comment: for ignorant souls like me pls check this link for strict aliasing http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html

Comment: This will swap `vpa` and `vpb`, not `pa` and `pb`. What's the point? Could just as well say `void* vpa = pb; void* vpb = pa;`.

Comment: @n.m. Gr8 observation i think after SWAP_POINTERS call we need to do int* pa = int* (vpa); int* pb = int* (vpb)

Comment: @n.m.: Of course it does. What's your point? The function swaps void pointer references after all. I showed how to call the function properly and not how to swap `pa` and `pb`. I consider the fact that passing `vpa` and `vpb` to `SWAP_POINTERS` will swap `vpa` and `vpb` to be downright obvious.

Comment: "The function swaps void pointer references" No, it swaps void *pointers*, niot references to those. OP asks how to make it swap *integer pointers*.

Comment: @n.m.: Yeah I meant that it swaps the pointer *via* references... and no ...OP actually asks why he cannot pass the pointers to the shown function. It is a XY-problem where I solved Y instead of X but 
Roddy already solved X and I actually refrain from solving X in this case.

Comment: @Kapil Yes, you can swap two integer pointers with four assignments and a function call, but I don't think you really want to. There are simpler ways to do the job.

Comment: @Kapil: The answer merely shows how to call that function with `void&*` arguments fromn `int*` pointers. Swapping pointers would be done via `std::swap` in actual code anyway.

Comment: Swapping two pointers `pa` and `pb` means `pa` should assume the value `pb` used to have, and vice versa. Creating some other unrelated pointers like `vpa` and `vpb` with whatever values doesn't solve the problem of swapping `pa` and `pb`. You need to come up with some code that does the equivalent of `int* tmp = pa; pa = pb; pb = tmp;` and preferably be clearer and not much longer that that. If one needs to swap void pointers, `SWAP_POINTERS(vpa, vpb)` barely fits the bill. If swapping int pointers involves tacking temporary variables and assignments on top of that, thanks but no thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115644/discussion-between-pixelchemist-and-n-m).