# Windows Driver: ZwReadFile returns STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: c++, windows, driver

In learning how to write Windows drivers, I am modifying the [Windows Driver Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples) for the AvsCamera.

I want to replace the simulated image with one from a bitmap file. In the `Synthesizer.cpp` file, I have commented out the calls to `SynthesizeBars()`, `ApplyGradient()`, and `EncodeNumber()` within the `Synthesize()` method, and replaced them with this code:

```
KIRQL level = KeGetCurrentIrql();
if( level == PASSIVE_LEVEL ) {
    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "Ok to perform file io.");
    UNICODE_STRING filename;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES fileAttr;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK fhStatus;
    HANDLE fh;
    NTSTATUS status;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&filename, L"\\SystemRoot\\AvsCameraTest.bmp");
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&fileAttr, &filename, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, NULL);
    status = ZwOpenFile(&fh, FILE_READ_DATA, &fileAttr, &fhStatus, 0, FILE_RANDOM_ACCESS);
    if( NT_SUCCESS(status) ) {
        status = ZwReadFile(&fh, NULL, NULL, NULL, &fhStatus, m_Buffer, m_Length, /*&byteOffset*/NULL, NULL);
        if( NT_SUCCESS(status) ) {
            DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "Read bitmap file success.\n");
        } else DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "Unable to read bitmap file [0x%x].\n", status);
        ZwClose(fh);
    } else DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "Unable to open bitmap file [0x%x].\n", status);
} else DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "Do not perform file io at IRQ level 0x%x.\n", level);
```

This is my first step: I am aware that I'm ignoring the bmp header.

The call to `ZwOpenFile()` is successful, but `ZwReadFile()` returns `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE`.

I've tried using a `LARGE_INTEGER byteOffset`, and `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` instead of `FILE_RANDOM_ACCESS`. I've also tried using `ZwCreateFile()` with `GENERIC_READ` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY` parameters.

I have been successful in writing to a file using similar code.

What is the issue with my attempt at acquiring the proper filehandle for reading?

Comment: `ZwReadFile(&fh` Why do you pass the *address* of the handle there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a pointer to the `HANDLE` variable itself when you should be passing the value of the `HANDLE` instead.

Change this:

```
status = ZwReadFile(&fh, ...);
```

To this:

```
status = ZwReadFile(fh, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks. It's strange that I didn't get a compiler warning about that. I'm still getting an invalid handle status back, though.

Comment: Correction: now it is a STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER error. At least now I know where to look next. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, `HANDLE` is typedef'd as `void *` and [both C and C++ will implicitly convert any kind of pointer to a void pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1736841/886887).