# Contiki Cooja error "Executing MSP430X instruction but MCU is not a MSP430X"

Tags: c, contiki, cooja

I am running a code in Cooja simulator on Contiki and I got the following error message:

> Executing MSP430X instruction but MCU is not a MSP430X

I want to broadcast a structure named `ReqMsg`. The `structure.h` file has been defined as below:

```
   typedef struct {

    int id ;

    int t1 ;

    int t2 ;

    char op[4];

    char E[2][2][4];

    char S[2][2][4];

    char type[20];

}EventPattern; 

typedef struct {

    int id;

    EventPattern epin;

    EventPattern epout;

    EventPattern epresolved;

    int remainEnergy;

}ReqMsg;
```

I gave values to `ReqMsg r` as below :

```
    EventPattern ep1 = {1, 1, 20,{{"a"} , {"b"}} ,{"seq"},{{"seq","a"},{"seq", "b"}}, "re"};
    EventPattern ep2 = {2, 1, 20,{{"a"} , {"b"}} ,{"seq"},{{"seq","a"},{"seq", "b"}}, "re"};
    EventPattern ep3 = {3, 1, 20,{{"a"} , {"b"}} ,{"seq"},{{"seq","a"},{"seq", "b"}}, "re"};
    ReqMsg r = {1, ep1, ep2, ep3, 5};
```

and to broadcast the ReqMsg I used packetbuffer as below :

```
    const ReqMsg *req = &r;
    const void *reqAdd = &req;
    packetbuf_copyfrom(reqAdd, 6);
    broadcast_send(&broadcast);
```

I changed the `buflen` parameter in `packetbuf_copyfrom` macro to 8, 10, 255 and 3512. the error message for all the values where the same. The Contiki error log in the simulation is :

```
    Executing MSP430X instruction but MCU is not a MSP430X
    Stack Trace: number of calls: 2 PC: $00002
    InterruptVectors (memset.c) called from PC: $062ca (elapsed: 5)
    rtimer_run_next (memset.c) called from PC: $05b38 (elapsed: 24)
    *** Interrupt 6 from PC: $042b8
```

and the java error log is :

```
    org.contikios.cooja.ContikiError
at org.contikios.cooja.mspmote.MspMote.execute(MspMote.java:341)
at org.contikios.cooja.mspmote.MspMote.execute(MspMote.java:298)
at org.contikios.cooja.motes.AbstractWakeupMote$1.execute(AbstractWakeupMote.java:47)
at org.contikios.cooja.Simulation.run(Simulation.java:280)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: se.sics.mspsim.core.EmulationException: Executing MSP430X 
instruction but MCU is not a MSP430X
at se.sics.mspsim.core.MSP430Core.emulateOP(MSP430Core.java:1079)
at se.sics.mspsim.core.MSP430.stepMicros(MSP430.java:253)
at org.contikios.cooja.mspmote.MspMote.execute(MspMote.java:337)
... 4 more
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "Executing MSP430X instruction" error typically shows up when there is memory corruption, and as a result the MCU starts trying to execute as instructions some memory addresses that do not contain actual instructions.

In your code:

```
const ReqMsg *req = &r;
const void *reqAdd = &req;
packetbuf_copyfrom(reqAdd, 6);
```

the variable `reqAdd` contains the address of the `req` variable. Instead, you want to to set to the address of the variable `r`, which is equal to the *value* of `req`:

```
const void *reqAdd = req;
```

Even better idea is to simply do

```
packetbuf_copyfrom(req, 6);
```

or

```
packetbuf_copyfrom(&r, 6);
```

since there is no real need for the extra variables.

Comment: copyfrom macro has been defined in contiki and the signature is packetbuf_copyfrom(const void *from, uint16_t len)..

Comment: [Conversions to `void *` are implicit in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1736841/2435820). You already are using this fact in your code, in the line which assigns value to `reqAdd`.

Comment: Also, `packetbuf_copyfrom` is a function, not a macro.

Comment: I did not know the difference between macro and function. I searched about it. thank you

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? If so, please accept it.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it is not solved yet. it's major problem is about the size of the reqAdd. the size is equal to 1 byte. so I've changed the buf size parameter in copyfrom function from 6 to 1 and also I've changed it to 8. both new sizes did not worked well.

Comment: *size of the reqAdd [..] is equal to 1 byte* - this is not true.

Comment: *both new sizes did not worked well* - please provide a [mcve] how did they not worked. By the way, your `ReqMsg` is too large to be sent at once. The default packetbuf size is only 128 bytes.

Comment: so I should fragment the packet. thank you. I'll try this solution.

Comment: If you only want to send the first six bytes of the packet, it should work as is.