# how to make g++ ignore calloc pointer type error when compiling c code

Tags: c++, c, pointers, compiler-errors, g++

For example, the line below compiles ok with gcc,

```
float *m = calloc(rows*cols, sizeof(float));
```

but g++ complains about the pointer type mismatch like below.

> ../../../../../YOLO/darknet/src/gemm.c:33:22: error: invalid
> conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘float*

(maybe callc always returns void* in c++?)
Can I make g++ just ignore this pointer type mismatch error?
(I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736833/void-pointers-difference-between-c-and-c) but they say it's unavoidable. If we can use c code from inside c++ code without fixing this everywhere, it would be nice.)

Comment: Just don't compile C code with a C++ compiler. It won't work most of the time. C and C++ are different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is actually not to add a `static_cast` as eerorika suggests but compiling the C code with a C compiler. There are a number of subtle differences between C and C++ that can lead to unexpected results, and the compiler won't catch them all. So even if you change all the type warnings you might still end up with broken code.

To ensure that you can call the C code from C++ you should mark the code as `extern "C"` inside the C headers like so:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

[your definitions]

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: yes, I saw your comment in eerorika's answer and figure out I am supposed to use gcc for compiling darknet codes. I added `extern "C"` around contents in box.h. that was the only change and it compiles ok. (g++ also sees the header so it doesn't mangle the name). Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

> (maybe callc always returns void* in c++?)

Yes. `calloc` always returns `void*`. Both in C and C++.

> Can I make g++ just ignore this pointer type mismatch error?

I recommend to not attempt making the compiler to ignore the bug, but to fix the program instead. You can fix it like this:

```
float *m = static_cast<float*>(std::calloc(rows*cols, sizeof(float)));
```

Or compile the translation unit with a C compiler if it is written in C.

> If we can use c code from inside c++

Solution: Don't use one language inside another. Write C in C and C++ in C++. Interaction between the languages is possible by linking the translation units together.

Comment: hi, my intention was not to modify the original C code, so compiling with gcc was the better answer. (para's answer) (otherwise I have to fix hundreds of places). anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding C++, read its draft standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or the newer [n4860](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf) draft or buy the official standard from [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization) (or the equivalent standardizing organization in your country).

Regarding C, read its draft standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Evlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) or buy the official standard from ISO.

For both C and C++, refer also to [this website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/).

Read also this [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book about C, and that [*Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++*](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) book about C++.

If you are using a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), and if you are allowed to code [some plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) for it, you might code a plugin which conditionally would correct the source code, or suggest and send some correction to your favorite editor (e.g. [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)). Such an approach could take many weeks of effort.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65122675/841108) correctly explains, you should improve your source code.

PS. I happen to be capable to write such a GCC plugin (see [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) tech report funded by the [CHARIOT](https://www.chariotproject.eu/) European project), but I need to get funded to do so. Feel free to contact me by email.

Comment: Note that n3337 is a very outdated draft.

Comment: Yes, but I forgot the reference of a newer one.