# In c++ do we have any chances to change void* to unsigned int* without using casting operators?

Tags: c++

while I working with c++, I am getting some Axivion warnings while using casting operators, so I need some clarification about it, is it possible to change `void*` to `unsigned int*` ?

is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: No, implicit conversion from `void*` is not allowed in C++ in contrast to C.

Comment: In C++ you should generally avoid `void*` pointers. Or any pointers, for that matter. Why do you have `void*`? What problem is that pointer supposed to solve?

Comment: You cannot implicitly cast it, unless you write your own implicit constructor/operator. You **can** however, use `reinterpret_cast<MyType>(myVoidPtr)` to explicitely cast it. This would be the recommended way.

Comment: See [void pointers: difference between C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736833/void-pointers-difference-between-c-and-c)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Especially when working with Linux and its syscalls, it's sometimes unavoidable to not use them. But I totally agree that they should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: [In C++, conversions from `T*` to `void*` are implicit, but `void*` to anything else **requires a cast**.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1736841/12002570)

Comment: Why is using casting operators a problem? If you want to avoid them for some reason then try not to use void pointers in the first place.

Comment: @SimonC -- re: "You cannot implicitly cast it" -- there is no such thing as an implicit cast; a cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. The phrase you're looking for is "implicitly **convert** it".

Comment: @PeteBecker If IBM is free to use the phrase "implicit cast", then I sure am, too

Comment: @SimonC -- by all means, use muddy terminology and then explain what you meant by it, if that's what you like.